# Datareader already open in the view, complex object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, code-first, datareader

I get this message in the view :
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

This is my model :

```
public class Product
{
    [DisplayName("Id Produit")]
    public int productId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Nom du produit")]
    public string productName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Lien")]
    public string productLink { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Categorie")]
    public int categoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("categoryId")]
    public virtual Category category { get; set; }

     [DisplayName("Tags")]
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> tags { get; set; }
    public Product()
    {
        tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    }
```

In the view this is working:

```
<td>
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.categoryId)
</td>
```

But this is not working :

```
<td>
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.category.categoryName)
</td>
```

Actually if i try to navigate in the complex object i get the message about the datareader.
Any idea?  :s

Answer (score 0):

Actually i had to map like this :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
          .HasRequired(a => a.category)
          .WithMany()
          .HasForeignKey(u => u.categoryId);
```

Not sure why it resolve the problem tho

Comment: this is not an answer!

Comment: need to put these in question section, to have a better understanding of your requirement.